# Autoload file laravel 4 Failed

Tags: laravel, autoload

I need a quick help here.
When autoloading my class it throws me an error:

```
Class 'Applicant\Respository\ApplicantInterface' does not exist
```

I have tried and lookup some articles about autoloading including [fideloper example](http://fideloper.com/laravel-4-application-setup-app-library-autoloading) but still no luck. Here is my code:

tree structure

```
resultchecker
  +app
   +Applicant
     +Helper
     +Provider
     +Repository
       +Eloquent
         -Applicant.php
     -ApplicantInterface.php
```

ApplicantInterface.php

```
namespace Applicant\Repository;

interface ApplicantInterface {
    public function all();
    public function get();
    public function lookup();
}
```

HomeController.php

```
use Applicant\Respository\ApplicantInterface;

class HomeController extends BaseController {

    public function __construct(ApplicantInterface $applicantRepo)
    {
        $this->applicantRepo = $applicantRepo;
    }

    public function home()
    {
        return View::make('app.index');
    }
```

composer.json

```
"autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "app/commands",
            "app/controllers",
            "app/models",
            "app/database/migrations",
            "app/database/seeds",
            "app/tests/TestCase.php"
        ],
        "files" : [
        "app/Applicant/Helper/functions.php"
        ],
        "psr-0" : {
            "Applicant" : "app/"
        }
    },
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `ApplicantInterface.php` is not in the `Repository` directory, so you have to move it to make your structure look like follows:

```
resultchecker
  -app
   -Applicant
     -Helper
     -Provider
     -Repository
       -Eloquent
         Applicant.php
       ApplicantInterface.php
```

If it doesn't work, try running `php artisan dump-autoload`.

I also recommend you to switch from `psr-0` to `psr-4` autoloading:

```
"psr-4": {
    "Applicant\\": "app/Applicant"
}
```

Good luck!